# How to compare two date fields in solrnet?

Tags: solr, solrnet

I'm using solrnet for eCommerce application which is based on ASP.NET MVC4 with C#. I've two fields in solr called 'StartDate' and 'EndDate'. I want to display products that matches condition like current date is greater than and equal to 'StartDate' and less than and equal to 'EndDate'. Most of Products are having blank value of field 'StartDate' and 'EndDate'.

So, How to build this type of query in Solrnet?

Answer (score 1):

Solrnet support date range queries.

Try something like this:

```
var q = new SolrQueryByRange<DateTime>("ts", new DateTime(2001, 1, 5), new DateTime(2002, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7));
```

check [this test](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/82fa8a814afc8b0a9b8a36df055964b8c58b825d/SolrNet.Tests/SolrQueryByRangeTests.cs#L59) in the solrnet project  for examples.

Comment: I already have two fields says 'StartDate' and 'EndDate'. I want to compare current date with those both fields.

Comment: Maurizio's answer should meet your needs, as you are asking for a query to find all items that fall in the range between your StartDate and EndDate. Replace the "ts" field with the name of your current date field and replace the new DateTimes with your StartDate and EndDate.